# interested to do vs interested in doing something

Tags: word-difference

I am going to write down two similar sentences below.

(A) You are **interested to** learn accounting.

(B) You are **interested in** learning accounting.

I have two questions.

(1) If you want to learn how to do accounting, does (B) work?

(2) When do you say (B)?

I don't know the difference between "interested to do" and "interested in doing"?

Comment: I speak American English and would not use Sentence A. Only Sentence B. *Interested to do* doesn't sound natural or idiomatic.

Comment: You may be interested in taking a look at this link [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13102/interested-in-knowing-versus-interested-to-know) on the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

> I am interested to learn accounting.
>   I am interested in learning *(about)* accounting.

both have the same meaning and would be understood to mean you are interested to take courses in accounting to learn about it.

Comment: I've always used (and heard) the second (”interested in learning”).